# Get Cell Value from Excel Sheet with Apache Poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

How to get cell value with poi in java ?

My code is look like this

```
String cellformula_total__percentage= "(1-E" + (rowIndex + 2) + "/" + "D" + (rowIndex + 2) + ")*100";
cell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
cell.setCellStyle(this.valueRightAlignStyleLightBlueBackground);
cell.setCellFormula("abs(" + cellformula_total__percentage + ")");
```

But if there is in this case how can i check that my cell value contain error value like #DIV/0! and how can i replace it with N/A

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You have to use the FormulaEvaluator, as shown [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html). This will return a value that is either the value present in the cell or the result of the formula if the cell contains such a formula :

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/somepath/test.xls");
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis); //or new XSSFWorkbook("/somepath/test.xls")
Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

// suppose your formula is in B3
CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("B3"); 
Row row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol()); 

if (cell!=null) {
    switch (evaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(cell)) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            System.out.println(cell.getStringCellValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
            System.out.println(cell.getErrorCellValue());
            break;

        // CELL_TYPE_FORMULA will never occur
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA: 
            break;
    }
}
```

if you need the exact contant (ie the formla if the cell contains a formula), then this is shown [here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents).

***Edit :***
Added a few example to help you.

first you get the cell (just an example)

```
Row row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex+2);    
Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
```

**If you just want to set the value into the cell using the formula (without knowing the result) :**

```
 String formula ="ABS((1-E"+(rowIndex + 2)+"/D"+(rowIndex + 2)+")*100)";    
 cell.setCellFormula(formula);    
 cell.setCellStyle(this.valueRightAlignStyleLightBlueBackground);
```

**if you want to change the message if there is an error in the cell, you have to change the formula to do so, something like**

```
IF(ISERR(ABS((1-E3/D3)*100));"N/A"; ABS((1-E3/D3)*100))
```

(this formula check if the evaluation return an error and then display the string "N/A", or the evaluation if this is not an error).

**if you want to get the value corresponding to the formula, then you have to use the evaluator.**

Hope this help,
Guillaume

Comment: As far as I know, you don't "have to" use FormulaEvaluator, if you don't have a formula in the cell :) If your cells contain text or numeric values you can get them by `cell.getStringCellValue();` or `cell.getNumericCellValue();`. Your answer applies to situations where the cell contains a formula, there is no indication that's the case for the OP

Comment: @posdef : you're right, i don't "have to". However, if the cell does not contains a formula, the method "evaluateFormulaCell" still returns the value. I find it simpler to call this method than to perform special condition check, since i then always get  the value of the cell. However, this is indeed void if you're sure that you don't have a formula.

Comment: @PATRY: you have a good point... I was pointing it out just to make sure there are no misunderstandings.

Comment: @PARTY.. Thanks for your help But if there is a cell type of formula and after evaluation of that that cell formula it contain error value like DIV/0! error than how can i know that cell contain this error and how can i replace this with 'N/A' ?

Comment: in case of an error, the type of the cell is Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR. You can get the value of the error by the getErrorCellValue() method. affter that, it depends onn your needs : if you just need an standard error message ("N/A"), then just chek the nature of the content. If you need different error messages, the use a HashMap mapping an excel error message to your own (this is just an exemple)...

Comment: plz look at my code . I have added code snippest in my question

Comment: @PATRY: In my experience (POI 3.7), `evaluateFormulaCell()` returns `-1` if the cell is not a formula, so you still have to handle formula and non-formula cells slightly differently, i.e., getting your cell type from `getCellType()` instead. I edited your code for the extra check.

Comment: You can use WorkbookFactory.create(fis); so you don't have to create HSSFWorkbook or XSSFWorkbook explicitely.

Comment: Six years later it's still the only answer that speaks to that. But I have two problems with this method: First of all the methods "evaluateFormulaCell()" and all the CELL_TYPEs are now deprecated and then this method is very slow to browse a fairly small file (a few minutes for 150 lines of 6 cells). Maybe someone have a better way to do it nowaday ?

Comment: How to access values as we do in Pandas data frame?

Answer (score 12):

May be by:-

```
    for(Row row : sheet) {          
        for(Cell cell : row) {              
            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());

        }
    }
```

For specific type of cell you can try:

```
switch (cell.getCellType()) {
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
    cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
    break;

case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
    cellValue = cell.getCellFormula();
    break;

case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
        cellValue = cell.getDateCellValue().toString();
    } else {
        cellValue = Double.toString(cell.getNumericCellValue());
    }
    break;

case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
    cellValue = "";
    break;

case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
    cellValue = Boolean.toString(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
    break;

}
```