# Java POI : How to read Excel cell value and not the formula computing it?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, notimplementedexception

I am using Apache POI API to getting values from an Excel file. 
Everything is working great except with cells containing formulas. In fact, the `cell.getStringCellValue()` is returning the formula used in the cell and not the value of the cell.

I tried to use `evaluateFormulaCell()` method but it's not working because I am using GETPIVOTDATA Excel formula and this formula is not implemented in the API:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedException: Error evaluating cell Landscape!K11
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.addExceptionInfo(WorkbookEvaluator.java:321)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:288)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:221)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:320)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:213)
    at fromExcelToJava.ExcelSheetReader.unAutreTest(ExcelSheetReader.java:193)
    at fromExcelToJava.ExcelSheetReader.main(ExcelSheetReader.java:224)
Caused by: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.NotImplementedException: GETPIVOTDATA
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.formula.functions.NotImplementedFunction.evaluate(NotImplementedFunction.java:42)
```

Answer (score 147):

For formula cells, excel stores two things. One is the Formula itself, the other is the "cached" value (the last value that the forumla was evaluated as)

If you want to get the last cached value (which may no longer be correct, but as long as Excel saved the file and you haven't changed it it should be), you'll want something like:

```
 for(Cell cell : row) {
     if(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA) {
        System.out.println("Formula is " + cell.getCellFormula());
        switch(cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                System.out.println("Last evaluated as: " + cell.getNumericCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                System.out.println("Last evaluated as \"" + cell.getRichStringCellValue() + "\"");
                break;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: How about cached dates? Date cells are flagged Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC.

Comment: As with normal date cells, you need to check the format string to work out if it's a date or not. No change just because it's a formula

Comment: Thank you so much, had problems with references to sheets in other files that did not exist, so couldn't be evaluated, but still the values were cached!

Comment: Is there a reason why we should prefer cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString() (as shown in the above code) from cell.getStringCellValue()?

Comment: How to format `TYPE_NUMERIC ` to the value I saw in the excel? For example, cell.getNumericCellValue() got `0.0`, but I saw `0` in excel. I'd like to get `0`, not `0.0`.

Comment: In poi version 4.0.1 I had to slightly change the code from case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: to case NUMERIC: etc., as per this documentation https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html

Comment: For latest versions of Apache Poi the code above would need to be modified, e.g. `Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA` would need to become `CellType.FORMULA` etc
On the other hand, since version 5.2 there is this great method `setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells`, which makes it much easier in many cases, see also [DataFormatter.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.html#setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells-boolean-)

Answer (score 12):

Previously posted solutions did not work for me. `cell.getRawValue()` returned the same formula as stated in the cell. The following function worked for me:

```
public void readFormula() throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Path of your file");
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    FormulaEvaluator evaluator = wb.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

    CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("C2"); // pass the cell which contains the formula
    Row row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
    Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol());

    CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);

    switch (cellValue.getCellType()) {
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            System.out.println(cellValue.getBooleanValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            System.out.println(cellValue.getNumberValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            System.out.println(cellValue.getStringValue());
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
            break;
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
            break;

        // CELL_TYPE_FORMULA will never happen
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, `evaluator.evaluate(cell)` returned `null`.

Comment: Seems like copied from [this answer with more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578535/get-cell-value-from-excel-sheet-with-apache-poi?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Answer (score 3):

If the need is to read values from Excel sheets and having them as strings then, for example to present them somewhere or to use them in text file formats, then using `DataFormatter` will be the best.

`DataFormatter` is able to get a string from each cell value, whether the cell value itself is string, boolean, number, error or date. This string then looks the same as Excel will show it in the cells in it's GUI.

Only problem are formula cells. Up to apache poi 5.1.0 a FormulaEvaluator is needed to evaluate the formulas while using DataFormatter. This fails when `apache poi` is not able evaluating the formula. From 5.2.0 on the `DataFormatter` can be set to use cached values for formula cells. Then no formula evaluation is needed if Excel had evaluated the formulas before.

Complete example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ReadExcel {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelExample.xlsx"));
  
  // up to apache poi 5.1.0 a FormulaEvaluator is needed to evaluate the formulas while using DataFormatter
  FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();  
  
  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(new java.util.Locale("en", "US"));
  // from 5.2.0 on the DataFormatter can set to use cached values for formula cells
  dataFormatter.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells(true);
  
  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    //String value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator); // up to apache poi 5.1.0
    String value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell); // from apache poi 5.2.0 on 
    System.out.println(value);
   }
  }
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: The line with "dataFormatter.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells(true);" did it for me!

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative command where you can get the raw value of a cell where formula is put on. It's returns type is String. Use:

```
cell.getRawValue();
```

Comment: That method isn't showing for me [in the POI javadocs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html), are you sure your answer applies to this library?

Comment: Have a look here: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html

Comment: Ah, that's XSSF only. You should make that clear, as the Common SS model doesn't have it, nor does HSSF

Comment: The workaround here was all about getting value from an excel sheet cell. It's will support for all the file format supported by excel.

Comment: Nope, it won't, that method doesn't exist for HSSF so isn't available for `.xls` files - it's `.xlsx` only

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract a raw-ish value from a HSSF cell, you can use something like this code fragment:

```
CellBase base = (CellBase) cell;
CellType cellType = cell.getCellType();
base.setCellType(CellType.STRING);
String result = cell.getStringCellValue();
base.setCellType(cellType);
```

At least for strings that are completely composed of digits (and automatically converted to numbers by Excel), this returns the original string (e.g. `"12345"`) instead of a fractional value (e.g. `"12345.0"`). Note that `setCellType` is available in interface `Cell`(as of v. 4.1) but deprecated and announced to be eliminated in v 5.x, whereas this method is still available in class `CellBase`. Obviously, it would be nicer either to have `getRawValue` in the `Cell` interface or at least to be able use `getStringCellValue` on non STRING cell types. Unfortunately, all replacements of `setCellType` mentioned in the description won't cover this use case (maybe a member of the POI dev team reads this answer).

Answer (score 0):

SelThroughJava's answer was very  helpful I had to modify a bit to my code to be worked .
I used https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi  and  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng as dependencies .
Full code is given below with exact imports.

```
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellReference;
    import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.Sheet;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellValue;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FormulaEvaluator;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


    public class ReadExcelFormulaValue {

        private static final CellType NUMERIC = null;
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                readFormula();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public static void readFormula() throws IOException {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:eclipse-workspace\\sam-webdbriver-diaries\\resources\\tUser_WS.xls");
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

            CellReference cellReference = new CellReference("G2"); // pass the cell which contains the formula
            Row row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
            Cell cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol());

            CellValue cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
            System.out.println("Cell type month  is "+cellValue.getCellTypeEnum());
            System.out.println("getNumberValue month is  "+cellValue.getNumberValue());     
          //  System.out.println("getStringValue "+cellValue.getStringValue());


            cellReference = new CellReference("H2"); // pass the cell which contains the formula
             row = sheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
             cell = row.getCell(cellReference.getCol());

            cellValue = evaluator.evaluate(cell);
            System.out.println("getNumberValue DAY is  "+cellValue.getNumberValue());    


        }

    }
```