# Matlab - get formula from excel with xlsread?

Tags: excel, matlab, xlsread

In the documentation `doc xlsread` it is described that one can use `[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('example.xls')` to pull data from excel sheets into matlab.

I have a sheet containing formulas to be copied to other sheets, however `xlread` will take the interpreted formula *value* instead of the formula itself.  For example one formula is `=AVERAGE(B8:V8)` which is what I would like to pull from the sheet programmatically, but instead excel returns the value `0.810` which is what the formula would return.

Is it possible to extract the formula in any way with matlab?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/318498

Comment: @HamtaroWarrior I have seen that thread - it is not helpful... no one found a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible with `xlsread` only.

One example of using a COM Excel object:

Let's use a simple excel sheet for example, containing text, values and formula :

[image: excel snippet]

Then the following code:

```
xlfile  = 'test1.xlsx' ;
xlRange = 'B3:C6' ;

exl = actxserver('excel.application');                  %// Create a COM server
exlFile    = exl.Workbooks.Open( [pwd '\' xlfile] );    %'// Open the file
exlSheet1  = exlFile.Sheets.Item('Sheet1');             %// Choose the worksheet
strFormula = exlSheet1.Range(xlRange).Formula           %// Read the full range
```

Yields a nice cell array :

```
strFormula = 
    'This is text'       'hello'          
    'this is value'      '12.5'           
    'this is value'      '29'             
    'this is formula'    '=AVERAGE(C4:C5)'
```

---

If you know directly the address of a specific cell, you return a simple string:

```
cellFormula = exlSheet1.Range('C6').Formula             %// Read a single cell

cellFormula =
=AVERAGE(C4:C5)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I am already controlling excel elsewhere like this, but it is much slower than using xlsread so I would have preferred not to need it here.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible using `xlsread`, you have to use one of the APIs available to read excel files or access excel. To my knowledge the choices are:

- Apache POI which can easily be used via the [Java Bridge](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bringing-java-classes-and-methods-into-matlab-workspace.html). An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7609587/2732801)
- Similar to the Java Bridge, recent versions of Matlab can access Python Libraries like [openpyxl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl/). This requires [at lest Matlab 2014b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29189167/2732801)
- You can access the Excel Application via [COM or .NET](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-matlab-com-integration.html)