# Apache POI incorrectly printing cell that is auto formatted to time

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to print out a cell from an encrypted Excel workbook. The cell contains a time and when i try to print `cell.getNumericCellValue()`, the result is a random number, that seems to be dependend of the time within the cell, in this case `0.5208333333333334`. When I try to just print the cell, the result is always this date: `31-Dez.-1899`, independend of the time within the cell. Here is the cell within the Excel sheet: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUBh1.png)

I am using Windows 11, Eclipse Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0), JDK Version: jdk-17.0.2

This is the code executed:

```
        XSSFWorkbook wb = null;
        
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excelFilePath);){
            wb = ((XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(fis, password));
        } catch (IOException | EncryptedDocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        
        XSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1);
        
        System.out.println(cell); // results in 31-Dez.-1899
        System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue()); // results in 0.5208333333333334
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get cell values as `String` in the same format as in the Excel sheet, do using `DataFormatter` as shown here:

[Java POI : How to read Excel cell value and not the formula computing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608511/java-poi-how-to-read-excel-cell-value-and-not-the-formula-computing-it/71390145#71390145)

Code excerpt:

```
...
DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(new java.util.Locale("en", "US"));
...
String value = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
...
```

Or, if you want the date cell value, then do get the date cell value instead of the numeric cell value as shown in https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
...
    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
...
        case NUMERIC:
            if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
            } else {
                System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
            }
...
```