# Numeric value read as decimal during data-driven testing in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, decimalformat, data-driven-tests, test-data

I am trying to fetch test data from the excel sheet but it reads the integer value as decimal. Every integer value comes up with a decimal followed by zero.

1. I have used apache poi for data driven testing.
2. Method to fetch String values as well as Integer values from the excel sheet is common.
3. Have attached the screenshots of the excel sheet data, method for fetching test data from the excel sheet and of the Testcase.

Please suggest.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't use `toString` but format the value properly based on the cell type?

Comment: For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3562214/230513).

Comment: `Cell.toString()` is not the correct way to get cell values as strings. It gets the stored raw values as strings instead the formatted values as Excel shows them. Use `DataFormatter` for this task. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608511/java-poi-how-to-read-excel-cell-value-and-not-the-formula-computing-it/71390145#71390145.

Comment: I got it working. I manually changed the format of the values as Number in the excel sheet. Didn't need to change the code. Thanks anyway.