# Problem with function RANK.EQ in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm currently working in a Java project that involves the analysis of an Excel Sheet. The project is built on the Spring Boot framework, utilizing Apache POI version 5.2.4 for Excel Sheet processing.

While the application generally works well, I've encountered an issue with the following error in some files: "_xlfn.RANK.EQ."

I've attempted to resolve this by changing the Apache POI version, but unfortunately, this hasn't been successful. Any suggestions on how to address this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `_xlfn.RANK.EQ` is not an error but a function name prefixed with `_xlfn`. It gets prefixed by Excel because this function was introduced later than the official recommendation of Office Open XML. So what exact error you get? Full stacktrace please.

Comment: Hi @AxelRichter!. My main issue is that I can successfully retrieve cell values because this function is not working correctly and I don know how to solve it.

Comment: If it is only about getting the cell values, then since Apache POI 5.2.0 no formula evaluation is needed. There is `DataFormatter.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells` now to get the formula results Excel had evaluated while last save. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608511/java-poi-how-to-read-excel-cell-value-and-not-the-formula-computing-it/71390145#71390145.

Comment: Sorry @AxelRichter, I need formula evaluation in each cell to obtain the right value

Comment: Then you need implement your own Java code for that not  yet supported function. See https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html. Either you file an enhancement request to Apache POI. Or you try yourself and ask a concrete question here when you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RANK.EQ function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rank-eq-function-284858ce-8ef6-450e-b662-26245be04a40) is not yet implemented in Apache POI.

Thus either you file an enhancement request to Apache POI to implement it. Or you need implement your own Java code for that not yet supported function. See [Developing Formula Evaluation](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html).

But seems `RANK.EQ` and `RANK` are doing exactly the same. And `RANK` is implemented in Apache POI.

So all what needs to be done is evaluating `RANK.EQ` the same as `RANK`. That could be done by implementing `RANK.EQ` as `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.FreeRefFunction` which evaluates it's arguments using `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Rank`.

Code `EvaluateRankEQ.java`:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.FreeRefFunction;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.udf.AggregatingUDFFinder;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.udf.DefaultUDFFinder;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.udf.UDFFinder;

public class EvaluateRankEQ {

 public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("./ExcelWithRankEQ.xlsx"));    
    
  String[] functionNames = { "_xlfn.Rank.EQ" } ;
  FreeRefFunction[] functionImpls = { new RankEQ() } ;
  UDFFinder udfs = new DefaultUDFFinder( functionNames, functionImpls ) ;
  UDFFinder udfToolpack = new AggregatingUDFFinder( udfs ) ;    
  workbook.addToolPack(udfToolpack);
  
  FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
    
  for (Sheet sheet: workbook) {
   for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
     CellValue cellValue = formulaEvaluator.evaluate(cell);
     System.out.println(cellValue);
    }
   }   
  }

  workbook.close();
  
 }
}
```

This is using `RankEQ.java`:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ValueEval;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.ErrorEval;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.FreeRefFunction;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Rank;

public final class RankEQ implements FreeRefFunction {
    
 @Override
 public ValueEval evaluate( ValueEval[] args, OperationEvaluationContext ec ) {

  if (args.length == 2) {
   Rank rank = new Rank();
   return rank.evaluate(ec.getRowIndex(), ec.getColumnIndex(), args[0], args[1]);  
  } else if (args.length == 3) {
   Rank rank = new Rank();
   return rank.evaluate(ec.getRowIndex(), ec.getColumnIndex(), args[0], args[1], args[2]);  
  }
 
  return ErrorEval.VALUE_INVALID;
 }
}
```