# how to get excel column index by searching with cell text?

Tags: excel

I have a excel file which has header row and many columns. In row 1, column 10 i have cell value as 'Request'. i need to get this cell index by searching with the value "Request". Is there any way without iterating through columns (without using for loop).

Comment: Are there more than one cell with 'Request'? If there are more than one cell with 'Request', do you need the index of all the cells with 'Request'?

Comment: You'll need to be a little clearer as to what you want, and how you want to get it.  Are you using VBA or excel functions?  If you post a sample, that would help a lot.

Comment: I am using Soapui+Groovy to automate my test case with the help of Apache POI for getting data from excel. I need to write my request and response after execution in the same excel on the 'Request' and 'Response' columns. So i need to get the column index which has the name 'Request' in the excel file (it will always be Row '0', as it is header row). So that if i get the index number i can use that for writing my request in the corresponding column index on required nth row. I know we can access thro' for loop. but i am trying to find another way without using for loop. Please let me know.

Answer (score 12):

Sample: You are looking in range `C2:J2` and `H2` has `"Request"`:

```
 =MATCH("Request"; C2:J2; 0)
```

will return `6` (column H is the 6th column counting from column C).

Comment: I am using Soapui+Groovy to automate my test case with the help of Apache POI for getting data from excel. I need to write my request and response after execution in the same excel on the 'Request' and 'Response' columns. So i need to get the column index which has the name 'Request' in the excel file (it will always be Row '0', as it is header row). So that if i get the index number i can use that for writing my request in the corresponding column index on required nth row. I know we can access thro' for loop. but i am trying to find another way without using for loop. Please let me know

Comment: I don't know Apache POI, but Excel as built-in function `MATCH` which works in cells formulas and also in scripting. However I find myself preferable using programmatic methods instead of `Excel.WorksheetFunction` methods.

Answer (score 0):

The original question did not state using Apache POI to search the values of the title row. In this case you will need to use the POI methods `getCell()` and `getCellValue()` on row 0 and iterate through those until you find the value you're looking for, then use POI to insert the row - [How to insert a row between two rows in an existing excel with HSSF (Apache POI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785724/how-to-insert-a-row-between-two-rows-in-an-existing-excel-with-hssf-apache-poi). For examples using the `getCell()` and `getCellValue()` see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578535/get-cell-value-from-excel-sheet-with-apache-poi);

The Match formula listed will not work in your case since the formula doesn't get evaluated until the spreadsheet is rendered. But it's a great formula to use in Excel.