# Reading numeric value from excel format error

Tags: java, excel, numbers

I am trying to read numeric values from excel sheet
for now i have read excel sheet read it using `apache poi` api.

My problem is that I have long number in excel sheet like `123435578774` while it display like `1.23436E+11` I set value in excel sheet as original but when I read it in java code it displays like `1.23436E+11`

Here is my code sample:

```
HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
HSSFCell cell = row.getCell((short) 0);

if (cell != null){
    Object result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
    readNumber = result.toString();
    System.out.println(readNumber);
}
```

Comment: The type of getNumericCellValue is double, and what you see is the default format for displaying a double with that many places. Use formatting, convert to long (if applicable), see org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Cell Value from Excel Sheet with Apache Poi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578535/get-cell-value-from-excel-sheet-with-apache-poi)

Comment: @laune possible not duplicate because i have already read values from excel. I am facing format issue

Comment: @laune as getNumericCellValue() returns double value when i try to write it manually IDE says : integer number too long : for double value = 123435510774

Comment: Well, then use `long`: 123435510774L

Comment: the problem is in conversion from double to string, still its unresolved