# Safe way to export cell value as String

Tags: java, apache-poi

What is the safe way to get cell value as `String` using **Apache POI**?

For some non-empty cells I get the following exception:

```
com.monitorjbl.xlsx.exceptions.NotSupportedException: null
    at com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingCell.getSheet(StreamingCell.java:330)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter.isDate1904(DataFormatter.java:313)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter.getFormat(DataFormatter.java:309)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter.getFormattedNumberString(DataFormatter.java:868)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter.formatCellValue(DataFormatter.java:1021)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter.formatCellValue(DataFormatter.java:971)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter.formatCellValue(DataFormatter.java:950)
...
```

I use the code below to extract cell values as text at the moment:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

private static DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();

private static String formatCellValue(Cell cell) {
    return formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
}
```

The javadoc of the method says:

> Returns the formatted value of a cell as a String regardless of the
> cell type. If the Excel format pattern cannot be parsed then the cell
> value will be formatted using a default format. When passed a null or
> blank cell, this method will return an empty String (""). Formulas in
> formula type cells will not be evaluated.

Comment: Well your cell could be null?  Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578535/get-cell-value-from-excel-sheet-with-apache-poi

Comment: @SusanMustafa No. The cell isn't null. I saw it during debugging.

Comment: Seems your `Cell` is a `com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingCell`. That is not the same as a `apache poi` `XSSFCell` or `HSSFCell`. But `DataFormatter` needs a `apache poi` `Cell` to work with. See https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader#usage for how to use this streaming reader.

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks. I'll take a look at it. But it's strange that it works with the same kind of cell in other parts of code and Excel document.

Comment: @AxelRichter Ok. I see now. It is safe for a StreamingCell to call getStringCellValue() on it which would be not safe for a POI cell. Thanks. You can post your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your Cell is a `com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingCell`. That is not the same as a `apache poi` `XSSFCell` or `HSSFCell`. But `DataFormatter` needs a `apache poi` `Cell` to work with. See https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader#usage for how to use this streaming reader.

The [com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingCell](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader/blob/master/src/main/java/com/monitorjbl/xlsx/impl/StreamingCell.java) implements `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell`. But for many of the methods the implementation is simply `throw new NotSupportedException()`. So it works only for the methods it implements correctly.

But as of the current version it implements `Cell.getSheet`. So your error leads to the assumption that you are not using the current version of [Excel Streaming Reader](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader).

Comment: I'm using the current verion - 2.1.0

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader

Comment: I'm using https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.monitorjbl/xlsx-streamer or this one https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader/releases
When I use the latest dependency of your link I get lots of compile errors. For example `com.monitorjbl.xlsx.StreamingReader` isn't found any more... Is it the same library? If so, it doesn't seem to be very backwards compatible. Sorry, I've no time to resolve all the errors. I've to deliver a working solution quickly. So minimal changes to existing source code a highly desired.

Comment: @ka3ak: Yes, you are correct. Seems to be two different libraries. I was confused because https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader/blob/master/src/main/java/com/monitorjbl/xlsx/impl/StreamingCell.java#L274 shows implementation of `getSheet`. So source code on `github` seems different from binary `jar` on `maven`.

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to add the check to the mentioned method and call `getStringCellValue()` on `StreamingCell` which is always safe in contrast to calling it on a POI cell.

```
private static String formatCellValue(Cell cell) {
    if (cell instanceof com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingCell) {
        return cell.getStringCellValue();
    }

    return formatter.formatCellValue(cell);
}
```